# Get a Group ID from Bridge table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to get a Group ID key from a bridge table that looks something like this:

```
GROUP_KEY  DIM_KEY
    1        11
    1        12
    1        13
    1        14
    2        11
    2        12
    3        11
    3        12
    3        13
    3        15
    4        11
    5        11
    5        12
    5        13
```

I've searched a little bit a got this query:

```
SELECT b1.group_key
FROM BRIDGE b1
JOIN BRIDGE b2 ON (b1.group_key= b2.group_key)
JOIN BRIDGE b3 ON (b1.group_key= b3.group_key)
WHERE b1.dim_key = 11
  AND b2.dim_key = 12
  AND b3.dim_key = 13;
```

But this gets me 1,3 and 5, and I only want the 5, I can filter it further with a a count = 3, but my question is, is there a better way ? I'm using PL/SQL btw.

Comment: Since the conditions you specified match 1, 3 and 5 group keys, you need to specify more conditions to get 5 only. As far as I can see, you got the correct answer to your question.

Comment: @SzilardBarany I've posted my query with the count, but I feel it is very cumbersome, I was looking for something more elegant, I count on the Stack Gurus :D.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

if you are using Oracle 11g, try the following

```
 SELECT group_key FROM (
 SELECT GROUP_KEY, listagg(DIM_KEY, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY DIM_KEY) DIM_KEY
   FROM t
  GROUP BY GROUP_KEY) WHERE dim_key = '11,12,13'
```

Comment: the group_key is what I want to return, check out my response to Arion ;). Thx

Comment: @user1383116 : Ok, but under which criteria? why the group_key 5 is the one that should be displayed? because it has exactly dim_key 11, 12 and 13?

Comment: yes :), for example, if I provide the dim_key 11, I want to retrieve the group_key 4.If I provide the dim_keys 11 and 12, I want the group key 3. I'm expecting some dynamic SQL, but I want to define a "base query" first.

Comment: @RMartins : i edited my answer, if you are using Oracle 11g you can try this solution and pay attention to the parameter

Answer (score 0):

I don´t really know what you want. But if you want to the count to be 3. Then you can do it like this:

```
WITH CTE
(
    SELECT
        COUNT(GROUP_KEY) OVER(PARTITION BY GROUP_KEY) AS Counts,
        BRIDGE.*
    FROM
        BRIDGE
)
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CTE
WHERE
    CTE.Counts=3
    AND CTE.dim_key IN(11,12,13);
```

Comment: I want to avoid the count @Arion. This query works: `SELECT b1.group_key
FROM BRIDGE b1
JOIN BRIDGE b2 ON (b1.group_key= b2.group_key)
JOIN BRIDGE b3 ON (b1.group_key= b3.group_key)
WHERE b1.dim_key = 11
  AND b2.dim_key = 12
  AND b3.dim_key = 13
  AND b1.group_key= (SELECT group_key
                     FROM BRIDGE 
                     GROUP BY group_key
                     HAVING COUNT(*) = 3);` but is not really neat, I'm looking for a better solution. Thx.